# Add method not working when inserting integers from a data file into an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Set;
public class tester
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers1.in"));
        //this will create a buffered reader to read the file, read each line
        //and count how many lines there are so I can easily create my array
        int lines = 0;
        while (reader1.readLine() != null)//reads each line
        {
            lines++;
        }
        reader1.close();


        Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(new File("numbers1.in"));//new scanner to read the file
        int numbers[] = new int[lines];//creates my array with correct array dimensions
        while(reader2.hasNextLine())
        {
            int next = reader2.nextInt();
            numbers.add(next);
        }



    }
}
```

I am a beginner at this, so excuse the messy code. I am trying to read integers from a data file which includes a list of integers, each separated by a new line. I have to add each of those into an integer array, and for some reason the .add method from java.util.Set is not working, giving me an error message that states the add method cannot be found.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java `array` length is immutable. It doesn't have an `add` method.

Use a `List`

```
List<int> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

while(reader2.hasNextLine()) {
     int next = reader2.nextInt();
     numbers.add(next);
}
```

Or, if you need to use array only

```
int index = 0;

while(reader2.hasNextLine()) {
         int next = reader2.nextInt();
         numbers[index++] = next;
    }
```